# VBScript xmlDoc.save isn't working

Tags: xml, file-io, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm writing an ASP-classic page using VBScript, and whenever an error writing to the Oracle database occurs, I want to write an xml file and save it to a directory on the webserver.

Here's what I have:

```
Sub writeError(error)
    text="<xml>"
    text = text & vbCrLf &"<username>"&currentUser&"</username>"
    text=text & vbCrLf & "<date>"&Now&"</date>"
    text=text & vbCrLf & "<error>"&error&"</error>"
    text=text & vbCrLf & "<xml>"    

    set xmlDoc=Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.async=false
    xmlDoc.loadXML(text)
    xmlDoc.Save((Server.MapPath("xml/Error.xml")))
End sub
```

This takes the username, the current time, and the error message, and is supposed to write it to a file. I've used almost this exact same function before, and it worked just fine, so I'm not sure what's going on here.  Any ideas?

Comment: I figured out what my problem was.  Yes, it was the closing xml tag, and it was also because I had a `<br>` appended to the end of `error` and so the `<br>` was throwing everything off.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [G. Stoynev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21172133/1630171) already suspected you're getting that error, because you put another opening `<xml>` tag at the end of the string:

```
<xml>
<username>jbrown</username>
<date>01/13/2014 15:42:23</date>
<error>Your error message.</error>
<xml>
```

It should have been a closing tag (`</xml>`):

```
<xml>
<username>jbrown</username>
<date>01/13/2014 15:42:23</date>
<error>Your error message.</error>
</xml>
```

You can detect errors like this by checking the `ParseError` property:

```vbs
If xmlDoc.ParseError <> 0 Then
  MsgBox xmlDoc.ParseError.Reason
End If
```

which would've given you the following message:

> The following tags were not closed: xml, xml.

I would *not* recommend simply writing an XML string to a file, though, because that way invalid XML will go undetected until someone tries to work with the file. Don't construct XML by string concatenation, but use the appropriate methods instead.

```vbs
Set rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xml")

Set userNode  = xmlDoc.CreateElement("username")
userNode.text = currentUser
rootNode.AppendChild userNode

Set dateNode  = xmlDoc.CreateElement("date")
dateNode.text = Now
rootNode.AppendChild dateNode

Set errorNode  = xmlDoc.CreateElement("error")
errorNode.text = error
rootNode.AppendChild errorNode

xmlDoc.Save Server.MapPath("xml/Error.xml")
```

You could simplify that a little by wrapping child node creation in a function:

```vbs
Function NewNode(name, value)
  Set node = xmlDoc.CreateElement(name)
  node.text = value
  Set NewNode = node
End Function

Set rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xml")

rootNode.AppendChild NewNode("user", currentUser)
rootNode.AppendChild NewNode("date", Now)
rootNode.AppendChild NewNode("error", error)

xmlDoc.Save Server.MapPath("xml/Error.xml")
```

---

On a different note I'd like to suggest two other modifications:

1. `Microsoft.XMLDOM` is outdated. Use `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0` instead.
2. Remove excess parentheses. Unlike other scripting languages VBScript does not always require argument lists to be in parentheses. Read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) about the many, many different meanings of parentheses in VBScript (and the interesting situations that can create).

Comment: Thanks for the great advice.  Oddly, though, this still isn't writing the file.  I can't figure out why it won't write though

Comment: It appears to be getting stuck on the Set rootNode line.  I put a response.write directly after it, and nothing is displaying

Comment: Got it.  There was a `<br>` appended to the end of `error`, and it wasn't liking that.  Your xmlDoc.ParseError is what helped me solve it, so I'm going to give the correct answer to you.  Also, I like the way you showed to do child nodes.

Comment: @AlexKibler Angular brackets must be encoded in text nodes. Replace `<br>` with `&lt;br&gt;`.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably your closing xml tag.

You could also use the FSO to write as text file, instead of using the XML activeX.

Something like this

```
outFile="xml/Error.xml"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
objFile.WriteLine "<xml>"
...
objFile.Close
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the error. However, I would **not** recommend writing hand-crafted XML strings to text files. That will only delay detection of errors like the one the OP made.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried this, and it still doesn't seem to be working.  I just have it simply writing <xml></xml> to see if the file will write, and nothing's happening

Comment: I believe it's hanging on the Set objFile line.  I put a response.write directly after it, and nothing is happening.